# Connect Api.ai to node red

Tags: http, websocket, webhooks, node-red, dialogflow-es

Is there a way to post to Node red and receive data from a node with api.ai?

I saw [this example on the site](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook#webhook-example), and want do make more or less the same with node red.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Setting up HTTP endpoints is perfectly possible with Node-RED. There are 2 nodes in the standard palette to do just that

- `HTTP in` To listen for an incoming HTTP request
- `HTTP response` To send a response back

The `HTTP in` node should start a flow and the `HTTP response` should end that flow.

Comment: At the moment i use IFTTT to post to Node-red and then i use HTTP to post back to IFTTT and display the message on my Device. I would like to use the Google Assistant to answer directly with api.ai. Is there a documentation for this?